# Why is my click event called twice in jquery?

Tags: checkbox, onclick, click, jquery

Why is my click event fired twice in jquery?

HTML

```
<ul class=submenu>
    <li><label for=toggle><input id=toggle type=checkbox checked>Show</label></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
$("ul.submenu li:contains('Show')").on("click", function(e) {
    console.log("toggle");
    if ($(this).find("[type=checkbox]").is(":checked")) console.log("Show");
    else console.log("Hide");
});
```

This is what I get in console:

```
toggle                     menu.js:39
Show                       menu.js:40
toggle                     menu.js:39
Hide                       menu.js:41


> $("ul.submenu li:contains('Show')")
[<li>​                                            ]
    <label for=​"toggle">​
      <input id=​"toggle" type=​"checkbox" checked>​
      "Show"
    </label>​
</li>​
```

Comment: Only fires once when I try it here http://jsfiddle.net/LRjUc/

Comment: @DominicGreen: It depends on whether you click the label or the checkbox (or the `li`). If you click the label, then at least on Chrome, you get both events.

Comment: Yes, it's a little difficult to see but if you select the last text on the console, you can see the event fired twice after that.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If I remember correctly, I've seen this behavior on at least some browsers, where clicking the `label` *both* triggers a click on the `label` *and* on the `input`.

So if you ignore the events where `e.target.tagName` is `"LABEL"`, you'll just get the one event. At least, that's what I get in my tests:

- [Example with both events](http://jsbin.com/iRozUd/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/iRozUd/1/edit)
- [Example filtering out the `e.target.tagName = "LABEL"` ones](http://jsbin.com/iRozUd/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/iRozUd/2)

Comment: yes, you're right. I can also fire the event only for the checkbox like $("ul.submenu li:contains('Show borders') [type=checkbox]").on("click",callback); , thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @shuji: Ah, okay, I thought you were hooking it on the `li` for a specific reason. :-)

Comment: Not really, it's just that this is the first time i use checkbox for my menus, so I was used to bind directly to li.

Comment: Could you use the `change` event here instead? that might fix your problem as well: http://jsbin.com/iRozUd/3

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker that added to the checkbox bind has the exact same result but I think it would be more proper for a checkbox.

Comment: This just saved me a few hours of hair pulling. Thanks, mate.

Answer (score 9):

I recommend you use the `change` event on the `input[type="checkbox"]` which will only be triggered once. So as a solution to the above problem you might do the following:

```
$("#toggle").on("change", function(e) {
  if ($(this).is(":checked"))
    console.log("toggle: Show");
  else
    console.log("toggle: Hide");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ssrboq3w/

The vanilla JS version using `querySelector` which isn't compatible with older versions of IE:

```
document.querySelector('#toggle').addEventListener('change',function(){
  if(this.checked)
    console.log('toggle: Show');
  else
    console.log('toggle: Hide');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rp6vsyh6/

Comment: Should be the accepted answer as it sounds much more logical

Answer (score 5):

This behavior occurs when the `input` tag is structured within the `label` tag:

```
<label for="toggle"><input id="toggle" type="checkbox" checked>Show</label>
```

If the `input` checkbox is placed outside `label`, with the use of the `id` and `for` attributes, the multiple firing of the `click` event will not occur:

```
<label for="toggle">Show</label>
<input id="toggle" type="checkbox" checked>
```

Comment: unfortunately, even after separation, the issue is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why this wasn't mentioned. But if:

1. You don't want to move the `input` outside of the `label` (possibly because you don't want to alter the HTML).
2. Checking by `e.target.tagName` or even `e.target` doesn't work for
   you because you have other elements inside the label
   (in my case it had spans holding an SVG with a `path` so `e.target.tagName` sometimes showed SVG and other times it showed PATH).
3. You want the click handler to stay on the `li` (possibly because you have
   other items in the `li` besides the checkbox).

Then this should do the trick nicely.

```
$('label').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$('#toggle').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).closest('li').trigger('click');
});
```

Then you can write your own `li` click handler without worrying about events being triggered twice. Personally, I prefer to use a `data-selected` attribute that changes from `false` to `true` and vice versa each time the `li` is clicked instead of relying on the `input`'s value:

```
$('ul.submenu li').on('click', function() {
  let _li = $(this),
      ticked = _li.attr('data-selected');
  
  ticked = (ticked === 'false') ? true : false;
  _li.attr('data-selected', ticked);
  _li.find('#toggle').prop('checked', ticked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that when I had the click (or change) event defined in a location in the code that was called multiple times, this issue occurred. Move definition to click event to document ready and you should be all set.