# Why click event is fired twice?

Tags: javascript, html, events, addeventlistener

Can someone tell me, why the event is fired twice for the following code:
[http://jsfiddle.net/m8heyzgz/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/m8heyzgz/4/)
Please open your console, firefox or chrome have console and watch the result after
you click on 'div1', then
The event walk through sequence will be:

- div3
- div2
- div1
- div3
- div2
- div1

As I know the capturing phase can be from top to bottom, and bubbling phase can be from the target to the parents nodes.

My question why, it's fired 2 times in the same order ?

HTML:

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2">
        <div id="div3">
            <form>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label>                            
                            <div>
                                <div>div1</div>                            
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <div>div2</div>                            
                            </div>
                            <div>                                  
                                <input type="checkbox" name="div3" value="div3" />
                            </div>
                        </label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
var d1 = document.getElementById('div1');
var d2 = document.getElementById('div2');
var d3 = document.getElementById('div3');

var f = function(e) {
    console.log(e.currentTarget);
}

d1.addEventListener('click', f);
d2.addEventListener('click', f);
d3.addEventListener('click', f);
```

Comment: Can reproduce in Opera as well.

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19595084/why-is-my-click-event-called-twice-in-jquery

Comment: @juvian, and if you add another checkbox under the first checkbox, you will get the first one checked. But why only the first checkbox is got checked in this situation if the new checkbox (if you add new one) is also under the same parent ?

Comment: Why only the first one? Because only one is syntactically valid. A `label` can be tied to only one element. Either by wrapping the element inside the `label`, or by setting the `label`'s `for` attribute to the element's `id`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## I. Why is the order same?

The 2 waves' order is the same, because **you only see the bubbling phase of both events, not the capturing**. If you wanted to see the capturing, your [addEventListener's third parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) (useCapture) should be true.

## II. Why fired 2 times?

1. The first click event is fired from the label, when you click on the label's content.
2. The second click event is fired from the label's checkbox, by a **synthetic click**.

---

**+1. What is a synthetic click?**

A click initiated by a program code, not by an input device. (It [fires a click event](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#fire-a-click-event).)

**+2. Why does the synthetic click happen?**

Because it is the 4th step of [the *run synthetic click activation steps* algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#run-synthetic-click-activation-steps).

**+3. Why is this algorithm run by the browser?**

Because it respects [the W3C's recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#labeled-control):

"The label element's *(...)* activation behavior *(...)* should match the platform's label behavior." "For example, on platforms where clicking a checkbox label checks the checkbox, clicking the label (...) could trigger the user agent to run synthetic click activation steps on the input element, as if the element itself had been triggered by the user *(...)*"

Comment: Credit goes to [CJ.](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1663278/cj) for the "anchor-perfect" link of the [relevant recommendation section](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#labeled-control).

Answer (score 2):

See the HTML5 spec:

"Except where otherwise specified by the following rules, a label element has no labeled control...

...**If the for attribute is not specified, but the label element has a labelable element descendant, then the first such descendant in tree order is the label element's labeled control.**...

...For example, on platforms where **clicking a checkbox label checks the checkbox, clicking the label in the following snippet could trigger the user agent to run synthetic click activation steps on the input element**, as if the element itself had been triggered by the user..."

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#labeled-control

Hence clicking on your label element fires a synthetic click event on the first input in the label - answering the question in your comments.

Comment: If you want to convince yourself, I've coloured up your fiddle to make it obvious what elements are firing what in your console http://jsfiddle.net/m8heyzgz/7/

Comment: I'm glad we could help you. Could you accept one of the questions, please? It's useful for future visitors to see the answer immediately. I tried to answer **both** parts of your question as clearly as possible, **without** the possibly distracting parts. If you can't decide, then [just flip a coin](http://justflipacoin.com/). ;)

Comment: @dany I'm happy that Tamas answered more fully initially and the effort he's put into updating it to an extensive and clear answer for future visitors is worthy of being accepted as the answer