# Ember js filter model hasMany content via checkbox

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am building a small educational app where the structure is as follows -

Exam `hasMany` Subjects and Subjects `hasMany` courses.

My model relationships -

```
App.Exam = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('string'),
    subjects : DS.hasMany('subject',{ async: true }),

});

App.Subject = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    description:DS.attr('string'),
    exam: DS.belongsTo('exam', { async: true })
});
```

Initially I display all the exams and on `exam/1` I display all the subjects belonging to that exam.

I am having trouble in filtering the subjects via checkbox

Here is the [Demo](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vupanacapi/2/edit?html,js,output)

Not able to figure out how to do it. Can someone suggest me how to approach this ?

Basically on click of `physics checkbox` only physics subject should be displayed in the view.

Comment: This maybe of some use http://blessanmathew.com/2014/08/16/ember.js-list-filtering-using-a-multiple-selection-filter-component.html

Comment: @blessenm - can we achieve the same via my code ? Please have a look at the demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am basically using the `MultipleSelectionFilterComponent` from my blog post mentioned in the comments. This component will take care of managing the selection of the different checkboxes and send a filter function to the controller. There you can use the function to filter the data. You can refer to my post for more details.

**[Here is the working demo.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yavoli/1/edit?html,js,output)**

The code looks like

```
App.ExamsExamRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('exam', params.exam_id).then(function (exam) {
      console.log("found", exam);
      return exam;
    });
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
    controller.set('filteredContent', model.get('data.subjects'));
  }
});

App.ExamsExamController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  filteredContent: [],
  actions: {
    filterBySubject: function(filterFn) {
      this.set('filteredContent', 
          this.get('model.data.subjects').filter(filterFn));
    }
  }

});

<ul class="list-group">
  {{#multiple-selection-filter filter-key-path="name" 
      action="filterBySubject"}}
    {{#each subject in model.subjects}}
      <li class="">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="item-checkbox" {{bind-attr 
              value=subject.name}}/>
          {{subject.name}}
        </label>
      </li>
    {{/each}}
  {{/multiple-selection-filter}}
</ul> 

<h3>Subjects Details - </h3>
{{#each subject in filteredContent}}
  <div class="col-md-3 well">
    {{subject.name}}
    <br>{{subject.description}}
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

Here is the code to the `MultipleSelectionFilterComponent`.

```
App.MultipleSelectionFilterComponent = Em.Component.extend({

  selectedItems: [],

  click: function(event) {
    var el = Em.$(event.target);
    var filterFn;

    if(el.is('input[type=checkbox]')) {
      if(el.is(':checked')) {
        this.get('selectedItems').pushObject(el.val());
      } else {
        this.get('selectedItems').removeObject(el.val());
      }
    }

    if(this.get('selectedItems.length')) {
      filterFn = function(item) {
        return this.get('selectedItems')
            .contains(Em.get(item, this.get('filter-key-path')));
      }.bind(this);
    } else {
      filterFn = function() {return true;};
    }

    this.sendAction('action', filterFn);
  }
});
```

Comment: This works thanks a ton. I will try to implement other filters in a similar manner.

Comment: If I console log in the component, the component's click event is being called twice even though there is just a single click event. Any idea why is it so ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19595084/why-is-my-click-event-called-twice-in-jquery

Comment: Oh I did not know that. Learnt something new. Thanks

Comment: How can I make the filter-key-path lookup for an array rather than a string ?

Comment: Its all in the component. You are going to need to customize it to ur need.

Comment: I replaced the following code with this in filter function of the component - 

return Ember.get(item, this.get('filter-key-path')).forEach(function(arr){
      return self.get('selectedItems').indexOf(arr);
 });

Looping it since it is an array. But its not working. Please help

Answer (score 0):

that is SIMPLY not possible in ember.js
yeahhh it sux