# How to prevent a JQuery click reoccuring without preventing default?

Tags: jquery, click, preventdefault

I'm having a not uncommon problem: I have a "click" event that is running twice per click.

```
<label class='refinement genre-refinement'>
  <input type='checkbox' />
  <div class='refinement-checkbox'></div>
</label>

$(".genre-refinement").click(function() {
  console.log("Once or twice?");
}
```

This seems to be caused because I have a customised CSS checkbox (it works just once when the CSS is removed).

I have tried preventing default but that blocks the custom checkbox checking. Something like one("click") isn't appropriate because the label needs to be available to be checked and unchecked on whim. I have also tried moving my checkboxes outside of the label, which does not seem to do the trick.

I figure I can solve the problem by putting a checkmark into my JQuery and forgoing the customised checkbox but I'm hoping there might be an alternative.

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: can you please show us working code for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my click event called twice in jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19595084/why-is-my-click-event-called-twice-in-jquery)

Comment: can you show the css? I think my answer is not correct

Comment: Thanks all. I've created a simplified version on Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/yM6PDWjk4mYS0QA7U85N?p=preview

Comment: You'll see that preventing default stops the checkbox from checking.

Answer (score 0):

How about disabling the control.

```
$(".genre-refinement").click(function() {
  console.log("Once or twice?");
  $(this).prop('disabled', true);
}
```

But it's weird why the click was called twice.

Answer (score 0):

Use change event on checkbox instead

```
$(".genre-refinement :checkbox").change(function() {
      var isChecked = this.checked;
});
```

It's still a  mystery why you would get your click event happening twice though